# Популярность JAVA после замены android'a Fuchsia OS

Tags: java, java-ee

Как вы считаете, сбросит ли в популярности java после окончания поддержки android и полного перехода на Fuchsia OS ( к 2022-23 г.)? Отразится ли это на зарплатах разработчиков или сектор android'a не столь велик по отношению к Enterprise проектам ? Стоит ли загадывать на 5 лет вперёд?  А что будет с kotlin вообще не ясно .

Comment: Fuchsia OS - эксперимент, который вполне может и провалиться. > Стоит ли загадывать на 5 лет вперёд Если есть свободное время, то можете почитать про [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) - фреймворк на Dart'е, который используется для написания приложений под Fuchsia. Можете почитать гайд [для Android разработчиков](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/).

Comment: Разве дата окончания поддержки Android и перехода на какую-либо другую ОС уже определена?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, к 2021 г. в планах поставить эту oc на продукты умного дома google , а спустя пару лет и полностью перейти на использование как основной мобильной oc . Поддержка android прекратится

Comment: Можно ссылку на официальные источники?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я думаю вы и сами можете прогуглить эту информацию .Поисковой запрос" google определила дату смерти android" , например https://www.sb.by/articles/google-nazval-datu-smerti-android.html . Ну и есть уже пробная web-версия, тоже поищите

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  https://akket.com/android/121966-google-nazvala-datu-smerti-android.html

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev https://mgoulao.github.io/fuchsia-web-demo/

Comment: Это не официальные источники, это жёлтая пресса. Сами представители Google ничего не говорили ни о том, что Fuchsia OS заменит Android, ни тем более о дате этого события.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  по словам rambler https://news.rambler.ru/internet/40600310-google-nazval-datu-smerti-android/  эту информацию объявили вчера. И почему вы так активно хотите опровергнуть то, что скорее всего это случиться и android не будет жить вечно. Да и над новым продуктом работают уже два года + есть демо версия. Я не хочу спорить с вами ни о чем. Мой вопрос был в другом

Comment: И опять без ссылки на первоисточник. Где само объявление-то? Просто за 18 лет в отрасли я видел уж очень много объявлений о смерти чего-либо, поэтому верю только официальным заявлениям, а не перепостам на новостных сайтах.